# json+ld script is not shows valid or validation failed

Tags: seo, json-ld

**Can any one help here.?** **it will be appreciated.**

**JSON+ld script was fine a while ago and now its shows not valid. any thing changed or script is wrong.?**

Test results : Page not eligible for rich results known by this test

Test URL : https://search.google.com/test/rich-results

1)

```
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "Person",
  "name": "John Doe",
  "jobTitle": "Graduate research assistant",
  "affiliation": "University of Dreams",
  "additionalName": "Johnny",
  "url": "http://www.example.com",
  "address": {
    "@type": "PostalAddress",
    "streetAddress": "1234 Peach Drive",
    "addressLocality": "Wonderland",
    "addressRegion": "Georgia"
  }
}
```

2. 

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
"@context": "http://schema.org",
"@type": "Service",
"name": "Fertilization",
"alternateName": "Weed Man Corporate Site",
"brand": "Weed Man",
"provider": {
"@type": "Corporation",
"id": "https://weedman.com/#Corporation",
"name": "Fertilization",
"alternateName": "",
"description": "Weed Man Lawn Care's slow-release granular fertilizer is exclusively blended for your turf, offering golf course-quality results. Request a free quote today!",
"sameAs": ["https://www.facebook.com/weedmancanada",
"https://twitter.com/weedmanlawncare",
"https://www.youtube.com/user/weedmancanada",
"https://ca.linkedin.com/company/weed-man-lawn-care",
"https://www.pinterest.ca/weedmanlawncare/"
],
"brand": {
"@type": "Brand",
"id": "https://weedman.com/#Brand",
"name": "",
"logo": {
"@type": "ImageObject",
"caption": "Weed Man logo",
"embedUrl":"https://weedman.com/images/logo.png"
}
}
}
}
</script>
```

**DATE** : 16 April 2021

Test result shows "Page not eligible for rich results known by this test" without any detail.

Comment: Google does not provide any rich results for Person or Service

Comment: would you please suggest us, what should we use if we want to crawl for services.? @tony

Comment: You can add service markup, but at the moment it does not cause any rich results in Google search. That's all the message from Google is telling you. It's not an error.

Comment: DON'T USE the `script` tag! Every SO question is about scripts one way or another